# How does pkill mask work?

Tags: linux, raspbian

If I have process named `raspivid` and process named `raspivideo` running and I execute command `pkill raspvid`, does it kill both processes or only process which is named raspvid?

If pkill kills both processes is there any linux-command to do the perfect match?

Comment: Do you mean you want to have exact match?

Comment: @HRgiger: Yes...I think that Tomas answer is right answer but pgrep should be replaced with pkill? Can't test it though.

Comment: @Redex you are right, pkill -x raspivid will kill raspivid only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pkill` kills all processes that command `pgrep` lists with the same parameters. In your case it sends **SIGTERM** signal to both processes.
The following command kills the exactly matching pattern only:

```
 pkill -x raspivid
```